# Getting only area name in google map ios?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, reverse-geocoding

I'm building an iOS app using storyboards.I have implemented google map in my app.

I'm using  [Feed Me Starter](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift) tutorial code in my app.I'm facing an problem,i'm getting in addressLabel in func reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) shown below:

Laggere Rd, JC Nagar, Freedom Fighters Colony, Kamala Nagar, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560086

But i want above address as Kamala Nagar only,means i need only area name,i'm unable to do this because i'm new in swift,could you please help me how i can do this.

here is my code:

```
 func reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response , error in

      //Add this line

  self.addressLabel.unlock()
 if let address = response?.firstResult() {
 println("label657656558568===\(address)");
 self.addressLabel.text=response.valueForKey ("subLocality") as? NSString;
 println("label===\(self.addressLabel.text)");
 let labelHeight = self.addressLabel.intrinsicContentSize().height
 self.mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.topLayoutGuide.length, left: 0, bottom: labelHeight, right: 0)
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) {
  self.pinImageVerticalConstraint.constant = ((labelHeight - self.topLayoutGuide.length) * 0.5)
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to assign the value to the address label,

Just do

Self.addresslabel=[response valueforkey @"streetName"];

Comment: Thanks @Geet i have applied your code it was giving some syntax error and i fixed it by using this:    self.addressLabel.text=response.valueForKey ("subLocality") as? NSString; but now my app is crashing and giving this error:       [<GMSReverseGeocodeResponse 0x7fbfba5d8510> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key subLocality.'

Comment: Log your response which you get in console, and check for the key being used to contain the street name , use that key here

Comment: I'm getting this:                                                  GMSAddress {
coordinate: (12.971599, 77.594563)
lines: Vittal Mallya Rd, D Souza Layout, Sampangi Rama Nagar, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560001
thoroughfare: Vittal Mallya Rd
subLocality: Sampangi Rama Nagar
locality: Bengaluru
administrativeArea: Karnataka
postalCode: 560001
country: India
}

Comment: if you are getting your desired display name in strret address key, then its correct

Comment: @Geet How can you use Objective C line in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

`address` is `GMSAddress` type.

So, you just can use

```
if let address = response?.firstResult() {
    self.addressLabel.text = address.subLocality
}
```

Learn more here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_address